# Get specific device type from a drive letter

Tags: winapi

I want to detect when a SD (or other card) is inserted into the card reader. I know about `WM_DEVICECHANGE` but I need to get specific device type information given the drive letter. For instance, I want to distinguish between any card in the card reader from an "ordinary" flash drive. `GetDriveType()` doesn't seem to be refined enough. What are my other choices?

I am happy with a Windows 7 solution. I do not need backward compatibility.

Is this type of refinement possible all?

I have found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583593/how-can-i-detect-when-an-sd-card-is-plugged-in) which doesn't provide a satisfactory answer. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077968/differentiating-between-data-card-and-pen-drive-or-usb-flash-drive) feels like the way to go but there is no sample code or pointers to sample code. It's unbelievable that nobody has pieced together a working sample for such a common request.

[EDIT]

I have also [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157438/interface-type-for-a-drive-letter). The sample provided has a few errors but after fixing it I still get no result. For a device which has a SD card inserted I get a `BusTypeUnknown` instead of `BusTypeSd` in `pDeviceDesc.BusType`. This seemed straightforward and still failed.

Comment: Have you tried WMI yet?  Win32_LogicalDrive and Win32_PhysicalMedia look promising.  Use the WMI Code Creator utility first before writing any code.

Comment: No. I have had only headache with WMI before. I try to avoid it whenever possible. Would WMI work in a Windows Service?

Comment: Hi, Did you get answer to this question? I need to do this too

Comment: To get volume/disk type without Setup API http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989713/get-drive-type-with-setupdigetdeviceregistryproperty/15662619#15662619

Answer (score 1):

This looks useful: [How Can I Determine Which USB Devices are Connected to a Computer?](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/03/15/how-can-i-determine-which-usb-devices-are-connected-to-a-computer.aspx)

```vb6
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colDevices = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * From Win32_USBControllerDevice")

For Each objDevice in colDevices
    strDeviceName = objDevice.Dependent
    strQuotes = Chr(34)
    strDeviceName = Replace(strDeviceName, strQuotes, "")
    arrDeviceNames = Split(strDeviceName, "=")
    strDeviceName = arrDeviceNames(1)
    Set colUSBDevices = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("Select * From Win32_PnPEntity Where DeviceID = '" & strDeviceName & "'")
    For Each objUSBDevice in colUSBDevices
        Wscript.Echo objUSBDevice.Description
    Next    
Next
```

Sample output (should be a tree):

```
USB Root Hub
Microsoft USB IntelliMouse Web
Microsoft USB IntelliMouse Web
USB Mass Storage Device
Disk drive
Generic volume
USB Root Hub
USB Root Hub
```

I hope not all USB storage describes itself as "USB Mass Storage Device". If it does, check the volume name or autorun.inf, if any.

Microsoft being among the inventors of USB, it's unlikely that you'll need [this Linux info](http://wiki.debian.org/HowToIdentifyADevice/USB#references), but it could be harvested for search terms like "Pendrive" and "Flash Drive".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible since card readers present their storage in the same way as a regular flash drive to the OS. They're both USB mass storage class devices. Here's the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_mass-storage_device_class) on this device class. The OS has no way of distinguishing between those two device types.